# Forward traffic to Docker issues

Tags: linux, networking, docker, port-forwarding

I have a few fundamental conceptual issues due to which i am not able to forward the traffic on a docker container containing a network.

Docker container is listening on 2123/udp

**Approach 0**
Publish all argument does not seem to work. There was no mapping/change in iptables before and after this command.

```
 docker run -d -P image
```

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

**Approach 1**
I want to send traffic from any interface/ip/port to a docker container. I found that most of my traffic is on eno1, ip = x.x.x.x and port 22. I tried binding this port 22 to docker using

```
docker run -d -p 22:2123 image
As the port is active so it could not bind with port 22
```

**Approach 2**
I chose a random port 80 and tried to publish it

```
docker run -d -p x.x.x.x:80:2123
```

I did not print any error. However, when i send packets to this ip and port, connection is refused.

```
Packets sent as follows.
dd if=/dev/zero bs=9000 count=1000 > /dev/tcp/x.x.x.x/80
```

Therefore i added a port forwarding rule to forward all traffic received on port 22 to x.x.x.x:80.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:80
```

Still connection refused. Even with this refused connection, i saw two transactions

```
 tcpdump -i any port 2123
 IP <dockerNWip>.37042 > <host>.2123: Flags [S], seq 1289990254, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 437161 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
 IP <dockerNWip>.37042 > <host>.2123: Flags [S], seq 1289990254, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 437161 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
 IP  <host>.2123 > <dockerNWip>.37042: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1289990255, win 0, length 0
 IP <host>.2123 > <dockerNWip>.37042: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
```

I am not sure where the problem lies. My question

```
 1) Do i need to bind x.x.x.x and port 80? I thought the rule would do that.
 2) Do i need anything else besides the publishing the ports?
 3) Is my way to tcpdumping the port correct to monitor the traffic?
```

My strategy/assumption was that binding host port 80 with container port 2123 should automatically route the traffic.

Comment: You say the container exposes port 2123 over UDP, so you should set your docker port bindings to be UDP:  `docker run -d -p $UNUSED_HOST_PORT:2123/udp $IMAGE` and see if that works any better.  If that still does not work, make sure the Docker network is in a functioning state.  Also, your test to check if it is working appears to be using TCP, you would want to switch to a test using UDP.

Comment: I have followed all of these instructions. However still don't see any traffic on port 2123. The binding is not successful.